# eBay Trading API restocking fee not displaying on listings

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am using the eBay Trading API with C# .NET SDK

I created a `ReturnPolicyType`

```
ReturnPolicyType policy=new ReturnPolicyType();
```

I set the policy properties and everything seems to work except the restocking fee

```
policy.RestockingFeeValue = "Percent_15";
```

And:

```
policy.RestockingFeeValueOption = "Percent_15";
```

I've also tried "15%" instead of "Percent_15"
but neither of them show the restocking fee on the listing

I've also asked the question on eBay's developer forums but they are pretty vacant of activity.

My full return policy code is below

```
ReturnPolicyType policy=new ReturnPolicyType();
            policy.Refund="MoneyBack";
            policy.ReturnsWithinOption="Days_30";
            policy.ShippingCostPaidBy = "Buyer";
            policy.RestockingFeeValue = "15%";
            policy.RestockingFeeValueOption = "Percent_15";
            policy.Description = "Returns are welcome on all items other than those sold on an 'AS - IS' basis. Buyers returning items shipped outside of the US will be responsible for all customs fees as well. Please read and fully understand the terms of our policy in advance if you wish to request a return.";
            policy.ReturnsAcceptedOption="ReturnsAccepted";
            policy.ShippingCostPaidByOption="Buyer";
```

The rest of the return policy displays as expected on the listing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fetched an item listed using our old listing method and looked through the API call log to see the XML format of the existing listing.

I noticed a tag `SellerReturnProfile` inside of a tag `SellerProfiles`

I was able to populate the tags in the `additem` call like so

```
item.SellerProfiles = new SellerProfilesType();
var returnpolicy = new SellerReturnProfileType();
returnpolicy.ReturnProfileID = 63410125011;               
returnpolicy.ReturnProfileName = "Returns Accepted,Buyer,30 Days,Money Default";
item.SellerProfiles.SellerReturnProfile = returnpolicy;
```

I had to list shipping profiles and payment profiles in the same way. It seems like if you list one seller profile the other 2 become required. In this case, the return profile was already defined in eBay as our default return profile.

They can be found in Account Settings -> Business Policies, but the id number has to be found with a `getitem` call on an existing item with the profile set.

It seems like the other call method `ReturnPolicyType()` might be depreciated as per these two sources

[Business Policies Opt-In out soon to be enforced](https://go.developer.ebay.com/coming-soon-business-policies-opt-inopt-out-will-be-enforced)

[Mapping Business Policies Management API Fields to Trading API Fields](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/business-policies/Concepts/BusinessPoliciesAPIGuide.html#mappingBPToTrading)

> Any seller who is opted into Business Policies will not be able to use the legacy fields at all, for Payment, Returns or Shipping in any new listing. If legacy fields are passed into the request, they will be ignored and dropped and the seller may get a warning message to that effect.

and

> If you pass in Business Policies profile IDs and the legacy fields, the legacy fields will be ignored and dropped.

Answer (score 0):

> To obtain the list of currently supported values, call GeteBayDetails with DetailName set to ReturnPolicyDetails. Then, look for the list of restocking fee percentage values in the ReturnPolicyDetails.RestockingFeeValue containers in the response.

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/ReturnPolicyType.html

Comment: Thanks trying this

Comment: Well that got me `NoRestockingFee` , `Percent_10` , `Percent_15`, and `Percent_20` which leaves me right back where I started

Comment: The documentation also mentions: "Restocking fees are only applicable to the US and Canadian sellers who have opted into eBay Managed Returns.". This might be an issue with the account you are publishing the listing to?

Comment: hmmm might have to look into if the eBay managed return has to be specified in the listing somewhere in the AddItem call. Thanks

Comment: Our other listings that are not done through this code show the restocking fee